# C# Registry cannot be written to

Tags: c#, exception, registry

I have an exception thrown when I try to write to an an existing sub-key within the CurrentUser registry.  It writes fine if the registry is null.  The exception is "Cannot write to registry key"

```
//create subkey
RegistryKey lo1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(KEY_NAME);
// If the RegistrySubKey doesn't exist -> (null)
if (lo1 == null)
{
    try
    {
    lo1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(KEY_NAME);
    // Save the the current date
    lo1.SetValue(KEY_NAME, DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //on error,
        return false;
    }
}
```

Later, if certain conditions are met, I want to overwrite the value.  I try using this line and have the exception thrown

```
lo1.SetValue(KEY_NAME, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Comment: Sorry, edited to include the exception verbiage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(KEY_NAME,true)
```

key should be opened as writable.

If that does not works try following.

```
  var user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
  var rs = new RegistrySecurity();
  rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
    RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.WriteKey,
    InheritanceFlags.None,
    PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow));

  var lo1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(KEY_NAME, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);
```

Comment: I tried, and still get the same error about not being able to write to the registry

Comment: can you provide what is KEY_NAME variable value ?

Comment: It is the app name "GOLD_2016_v1.0.0"

Comment: Try following, open regedit, find your key , Right click on the key and select 'Permissions'.
try adding "Everyone" and re-run your code.

Comment: The permissions were already set at full control.  What's I'm not fully understanding is why I can write to it the first time when it's null, but I can't set the value afterward.  I'm just a beginner, so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Try deleting value, until you reassign it. `lo1.DeleteValue(KEY_NAME );`

Comment: Now it gives the same exception on the DeleteValue line

Comment: @coolhand Try following 
`var user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" +        Environment.UserName;
        var rs = new RegistrySecurity();
        rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
            RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.WriteKey,
            InheritanceFlags.None,
            PropagationFlags.None,
            AccessControlType.Allow));
        lo1.SetAccessControl(rs); `

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  Although the "lo1.SetAccessControl(rs)" gave me a null object exception, I was able to get it to work by putting your registry security code in and then using it to declare the sub-key afterwards with " RegistryKey lo1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(KEY_NAME, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);"